# How to create correctly escaped file:// URI in C#?

Tags: c#, uri

What would be the correct way to create a fully URL-encoded `file://` URI from a local path, i.e. where all special characters such as blanks etc are escaped?

Given the following input

```
C:\Data\Input Document.txt
```

I would like to get

```
file:///C:/Data/Input%20Document.txt
```

I've been using

```
Uri uri = new Uri(@"C:\Data\Input Document.txt", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

However, this results in an unescaped URI:

```
file:///C:/Data/Input Document.txt
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is already encoded

uri.AbsolutePath should give you `"C:/Data/Input%20Document.txt"`

Comment: Thanks, I missed that. However, it is only working for absolute URIs as this property is not set for relative URIs.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

`new Uri(str).AbsoluteUri`

Not sure I understand your requirement for relative URIs...